# Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css

tengo este codigo y me sale este error
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined`

al darle click al abrir el modal me sale el error, pero le doy otro click y se habre y con el error, pero la idea es que habra el modal con el primer click

```
<button type="button" id="myBtn3" onclick="modal3()" class="btn btn-default">SOLICITAR DIAGNÓSTICO GRATUITO AHORA</button>

function modal3(){

            var modal3 = document.getElementById('myModal-3');

            var btn3 = document.getElementById("myBtn3");

            var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

            btn3.onclick = function() {
                modal3.style.display = "block";
            }

            span.onclick = function() {
                modal3.style.display = "none";
            }

            window.onclick = function(event) {
                if (event.target == modal) {
                    modal3.style.display = "none";
                }
            }

        }
```

Agradezco su ayuda

Comment: En cual de los 3 eventos te sale el error?

Comment: en el 3 evento sale el error, lo documente pero el modal se sigue abriendo pero al segundo click

Comment: Esto ocurre porque alguno de los selectores no encuentra ningún elemento que se ajuste al selector y no devuelve nada. Entonces al intentar añadir el `onclick`, recibes ese error. Debes añadir el HTML relacionado para ver cuál de ellos es el que falla (¿se llama antes de que el elemento sea creado? ¿se carga el modal via AJAX?).

Comment: no esta hecho con ajax

Comment: Una pregunta. Para que llamas a la funcion en el onclick del button, si despues vas a capturar el evento onclick del mismo boton?

Comment: con el onclick llamo la funcion y con el id del boton dentro de la funcion es que llama al modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elimina el evento "onclick" del botón, que quede asi:

```
<button type="button" id="myBtn3" class="btn btn-default">SOLICITAR DIAGNÓSTICO GRATUITO AHORA</button>
```

Elimina la funcion del script y modifica todos los eventos onclick del por addEventListener:

```
  var modal3 = document.getElementById("myModal-3");

  var btn3 = document.getElementById("myBtn3");

  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  btn3.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
     modal3.style.display = "block";
  });


  span.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
     modal3.style.display = "none";
  });

  window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
             if (event.target == modal3) {
      modal3.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
```

Comment: me funciono aunque quedo el código todo esparcido, pero funciono

Comment: pues como tengo 3 modulares independientes entonces tenia 3 funciones

Comment: Buenisimo! Si resuelve tu problema marca esta respuesta como la que resolvio tu problema (haciendo click en el tilde)

Answer (score -1):

Tienes un error: Es `event.target == modal3` en lugar de `event.target == modal`

```js
  var modal3 = document.getElementById("myModal-3");

  var btn3 = document.getElementById("myBtn3");

  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  btn3.addEventListener("click",()=>{modal3.style.display = "block";});

  span.addEventListener("click",()=>{modal3.style.display = "none";});
/*
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal3) {
      modal3.style.display = "none";
    }
  };*/
```

```css
#myModal-3{display:none; border:1px solid;padding:1em;}
.close{cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="myBtn3" class="btn btn-default">SOLICITAR DIAGNÓSTICO GRATUITO AHORA</button>

<div id="myModal-3">algo <span class="close">x</span></div>
```

Comment: Aunque esto soluciona un problema, no es el problema expuesto en la pregunta (si te fijas tienes que pulsar dos veces para que se vea el modal).

Comment: pues se quito el error, pero para abrir el modal, tengo que dar 2 clicks

Comment: Buenisimo! Si resuelve tu problema marca esta respuesta como la que resolvio tu problema (haciendo click en el tilde).

Comment: Creo que ahora funciona correctamente. Mirando bien tienes un elemento y una función con el mismo nombre `modal3`. Además no creo que necesites lo de  `window.onclick`

Comment: Copiaste mi respuesta